# Can I respec in Faery: Legends of Avalon?

Tags: faery-legends-of-avalon

Can I respec my faery in *Faery: Legends of Avalon*? If so, who/where/how?

Comment: I can't be the only one who's off-put by the odd spelling of fairy, right?

Comment: ["faery"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/faery) is an archaic way of spelling fairy. Makes it seem more Olde World.

Comment: Yeah, a cursory look at Wikipedia showed that, but it was still a but "wait what" at first glance. :)